# Writing to the end of a text file in python 3

Tags: python, text

I'm currently working on a bit of code that requires me to keep records of the outcome.
However, at the minute, the code I'm using only overwrites the document, rather than adding on.
What can I write to add something to the end of a text document?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You should show us the code you uses to write in your file.

Comment: Sorry about the original broadness, and I found an answer on the website too. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 5):

open the file in `append mode`

```
open(filename, 'a')
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use append mode:

```
with open('something.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('text to be appended')
```

Documentation [can be found here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 2):

Open your file with something like

```
f = open('myfile.log', 'a')
```

you can also check [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for more alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is correct about using append mode for opening files that you want to add to, not overwrite. Here are some links that helped me learn a bit more about opening and editing files in python.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

I am not sure if it's written in your code, but it is always a good idea to .close() the file when you are done writing to it. If it's not a terribly huge file it doesn't hurt to make sure what you appended is actually in the file. So it would be something like:

`with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
     f.write("Some string\n")`

`with open('file.txt', "r") as f:
     for line in f:
         if "Some string" in line:
             f.close()
             return True
 return False`

There are more concise ways to write this, but I wanted to try and make it as accessible to everyone as I could. Also note checking for the string I am assuming that exact string does not repeat.